# How to develop a universal framework in Xcode 6 using Git source control

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, frameworks

What would be the best way to develop a universal framework, that can be embedded in any other application.

My thought would be that I would create a new Xcode project application (this would be to develop a framework against, called AppFram1 in this example).  Then create a new target to this application based on the Cocoa Touch Framework (this is the framework I want to export and embed into other applications, called Fram1 in this example)

I develop the framework, then ...

Then I create my applications (two in this example) App1 & App2.  (This is where I get stuck).
I now need to import my framework into both of these applications.

**Option1**
If I build AppFram1 it generates the framework and places it into the DerivedData folder as far as I am aware, but these folders names change based on what computer you are on. This won't work if I am moving the code to my other computers or colleagues using source control.

**Option 2**
If I add the git repo for AppFram1 as a submodule to both of my other applications (App1 & App2), this way I have full source control support for my applications. However, now I can edit the framework from another application which is not ideal (maybe I am wrong about this?).
Also, if Fram1 has a submodule itself then the submodule does not seem to get loaded into the Fram1 project when I build the App1 or App2 project, this in turn fails the whole application from building.

**Option 3** 
Build Fram1 independently, but have it automatically placed it into a global frameworks folder somewhere on the Mac. Then in App1 & App2 link/embed this framework into the application, just like you do when adding any of Apple's frameworks. This means that there is a common place for the frameworks and easy access to them, and I do not have access to change the Fram1 code when developing the App1 or App2.

Which of these options would be best (or best practice) to use, or is there another way that I have missed to achieve this?